# Django: CommentForm Not Working Correctly, No Error?

Tags: python, django, forms

Attempting to create a comment form as follows:

```
class CommentCreationForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    author = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommmentCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        comment = Comment(body=data['body'], author=data['author'], user=self.user)
        comment.save()

    def clean(self):
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def create(request):
    try:
        if is_post(request):
            form = CommentCreationForm(request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                print 'valid'
                form.save()
                return render_to_response("login.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))
            return render_to_response("login.html", context_instance = RequestContext(request))
        return render_to_response("create.html", {'form':CommentCreationForm()}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

If I submit the form, it returns: 'User' object has no attribute 'get'. I'm sure I'm doing something very wrong, but I don't know what.

Comment: I think the problem is in your save method, try to this it like this:

Comment: comment = Comment(body=data['body'], author=data['author'], user_id=1). Put default user to test if it will save or not

Answer (score 0):

First, The form is incorrectly initialized, the signature of `Form.__init__` looks like:

```
Form.__init__(data=None, files=None, ...)

# When you put
form = CommentCreationForm(request.user)
# The data is feed w/ request.user ...
```

Second, `self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)` would always set `self.user` to `None`, unless the invoking code is:

```
form = CommentCreationForm(request.POST, user=request.user)
```

Finally, a better approach is to refer the `request.user` directly, in some scope, for example:

```
def make_commment_form_cls(user):

    class CommentCreationForm(forms.Form):
        body = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
        author = forms.CharField()

        def save(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data
            # HERE
            comment = Comment(body=data['body'], author=data['author'], user=user)
            comment.save()

    return CommentCreationForm
```

In create view

```
# replace 
form = CommentCreationForm(request.user)
# with
form = make_comment_form_cls(request.user)(request.POST)
```